# INSERT every USER detail into a table triggered by submit button

Tags: php

I have table with 10's of user details in it. i m trying to insert these user details into another table along with admin input. so, if admin inserts a code and submits the same, the code should get inserted into table along with user details available. Thus, there will be a row for every user along with that code.

SO far this is my code::

```
<?php include('db.php'); ?>
<?php

$code = $_POST['code'];


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

 $sql = "SELECT name FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                               
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$name = row(name);

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO table1 (code, name)
VALUES ('$code', '$name')";
if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {

echo '<a href="home.php"></a>';
}
    else {
        echo "ERROR" . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
    else {
        echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Please explain more in depth what you're trying to accomplish. Break it up into direct steps.

Comment: @Kray Hope i made the concept clear. i m trying to create multiple rows with existing data from another table at a time along with admin input data .

Comment: give me 2 minutes, I know what you're trying to do. ill write it out sec

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use PDO. Its easy, and secure.

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array());
$data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($q->rowCount() > 0 ) {

        $Name = $data['name'];
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 ("
            ."code = ?,"
            ."name = ?,"    
            .")"
            ." VALUES(?,?)";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($code,$Name));

        if ($q->rowCount() > 0 ) {
            echo '<a href="home.php">Click Here to go Home!</a>';
        }


    }
```

Note* there is a flaw in your "design" You have to also consider what if the name has already been inputted into the table? You can do this in a few different ways.

One way could go about it is, Once you've updated that name and code into the new table you can then run a stmt to `UPDATE` users table and update a specific column to Boolean on if the name has been transferred or not.

Otherwise every time this block is executed then you're going to input duplicate records into the new table.

Select * from Table

```
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, DO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($varhereforsearchingwherecolumnvalueequalsthisvarvalue));
    $Email = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

INSERT into table.

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO table ("
                                        . "columnnameetc,"

                                      .")"
                                      ." VALUES(?)"; // add ?, for each var you add.
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array(
                              vars here
                            ));
```

UPDATE

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "UPDATE table SET region = ?";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array(
            $vars
            ));
```

Comment: hey Kray, thank you for your time. but i have to admit, i dont have any idea about PDO so, until i understand the code i can't use it. so , can you please write down the solution in the format that i have posted the question. i understand its not secure and so, but i want to understand the logic here. its a request man. thanks.

Comment: How much I can understand your frustration as I was there once, I do want to help spread what was done with me, and forced me to learn. It is vary simple to do. Google a quick pdo CLASS and put at top of page. Run what I wrote and you'll quickly see its IMO a lot easier than mysql_ or mysqli.

Comment: If you think mysqli or mysql can be difficult PDO is cake walk. I'll post a quick snippet of how to UPDATE, INSERT, and SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to simplify your code to just 1 statement that does `insert from select` supplied by your `$code` value

`insert into table1 (code,name) select '.$code.',name from users`

Whole code would looks like

```
<?php include('db.php'); ?>
<?php

$code = $_POST['code'];

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = 'insert into table1 (code,name) select '.$code.',name from users';
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo '<a href="home.php"></a>';
}
    else {
        echo "ERROR" . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
    else {
        echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
$conn->close();
?>
```